# Irreducible unitary representations of locally compact groups 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $\mu$ be a left Haar measure. We know
that $\mu$ is unique up to a scalar in $\mathbf{R}_{>0}$. I don't know so much about unitary representations of groups but for the sake of convenience let us make the following definition:

Let $(V,\langle\ ,\ \rangle)$ be an Hilbert space over $\mathbf{C}$ of countable (finite or infinite) orthonormal Schauder basis. We let Let $GL_{cont}(V)$ be the set of bounded (with respect to the operator norm) linear operators on $V$. We may view $GL_{cont}(V)$ as a topological group via the discrete topology. Now let $M$ be a $\mathbf{C}$ vector space with a linear $G$-action. We will say that $M$ is a **unitary irreducible representation** of $G$ if there exists an abstract isomorphism of $\mathbf{C}$ vector spaces $f:M\rightarrow V$ (where $V$ is chosen as above) such that the natural map $GL(M)\rightarrow GL(V)$

(1) factors through $GL_{cont}(V)$

(2) $V$ is irreducible as a $G$-module

(3) For all $g\in G$ and all $v,w\in V$ one has that $\langle\rho(g)v,\rho(g)w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$.

Now let us consider the space $L^2(G)$ of all functions
$f:G\rightarrow\mathbf{C}$ where $f$ is measurable and square integrable with respect to the Haar measure. Note that this space has a natural structure of a $G$-module through left action.

Now in the special case where $G$ is a compact Lie group ($G$ is not necessarily connected so in particular this covers all finite groups) then all irreducible representation
are unitary (the average trick) and finite dimensional (this I think is non-trivial and follows from Peter-Weyl, actually I never looked at the proof of this result). Moreover, if
$\widehat{G}$ denote a complete set irreducible $\mathbf{C}$ representations of $G$ (up to isomorphisms as (unitary) $G$-modules) then one has that

$L^2(G)=\bigoplus_{\phi\in\widehat{G}}\oplus_{i,j}\sqrt{n_{\phi}}\phi_{ij}$ where $n_{\phi}=dim(\phi)$ and
$\phi_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of $\phi:G\rightarrow GL(V_{\phi})$. In other words all irreducible unitary representations (say $\phi$ is one of them) of $G$ occur in $L^2(G)$ with multiplicities $n_{\phi}$. The direct sum here should be understood in the sense of Schauder basis with respect to the topology induced by $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$. Note that
$\lbrace\sqrt{n_{\phi}}\phi_{i,j}\rbrace$ gives an orthonormal basis of $L^2(G)$.

Now here is a set of natural questions:

(1) Do all the irreducible unitary representations of a **semi-semiple** (reductive)
algebraic group over $\mathbf{R}$ occur in $L^2(G)$?

(2) On the other side of the spectrum, what about  algebraic solvable groups?

(3) What is the minimal example of a locally compact topological group $G$ (with an non artificial tailor made topology, in particular $G$ has to be infinite) for which one can find an irreducible unitary representation which does not occur in $L^2(G)$?

Comment: I think you have some sort of implicit assumption that "occur" will be as simple as the compact case, i.e. as direct summand. In this type of question, that is not how it works. But see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_harmonic_analysis fpr what to expect.

Comment: Hi @Charles, thanks a lot for your comment. So by "occur" I simply mean that if $M$ is an irreducible unitary $\mathbf{C}$-representation of
$G$ as defined above then there exists a continuous inclusion map of $G$-module $\iota:M\hookrightarrow L^2(G)$ which respects the inner products. And then because of the inner product one may define an orthogonal complement which "seems" to imply indeed that $M$ may be viewed as a direct summand!


Comment: Complementing Charles's comment: take $G=\mathbf{R}$ and the trivial 1-dimensional representation. It is not included in $L_2(\mathbf{R})$ since non-zero constant functions are not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: ... by the way, there is no need to take $G$ to be $\mathbf{R}$, one can take any other non-compact group instead.

Comment: Right, that is a good observation, so for $\mathbf{R}$, the trivial representation which is irreducible and unitary in the sense above
does not occur in $L^2(\mathbf{R})$.

So may be in the non-compact case, $L^2(G)$ is not the right object to look at. So what kind of object should replace $L^2(G)$?

Comment: Dear Hugo, See my answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37021/is-fourier-analysis-a-special-case-of-representation-theory-or-an-analogue/37189#37189 .
It provide a summary of unitary representation theory of reductive Lie groups, which is somewhat more complicated than what you have anticipated.  (Your concept of "occur" corresponds essentially to discrete series representations.  Not all Lie groups admit discrete series, and even for those that do, most unitary irreps. are not discrete series.)  

Comment: Also, your definition of irreducible is not so good; the appropriate concept in the infinite-dimensional concept is *topological* irreducibility (i.e. no proper invariant *closed* subspaces).
Finally for now, the discrete topology on $GL_{cont}(V)$ is not really the most appropriate choice, but this doesn't seem to affect your question, since it doesn't seem to be used anywhere in your question.

Comment: So in order to get rid of the obvious counter-example for $\mathbf{R}$ we could require "some kind of growth condition". For example, if $\rho$ is an infinite dimensional irreducible unitary representation  $\rho:G\rightarrow GL_cont(V)$ then we want something like for all $g\in G$ one has that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle ge_n,e_n\rangle\rightarrow 0$. But this is probably to naive...
 

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the link, I just read it. By the way, it seems that
$\widehat{G}$ is more than just a set. For example if I take $V_1$ and
$V_2$ two irreducible representations of $G$ then one may look at
the $G$ representation $V_1\otimes_{\mathbf{C}} V_2$ and decompose 
it into a "direct sum" of representations of $G$. 


Comment: In general there is no reason why it should be semi-simple but 
you get the idea... may be there is some kind of Jordan-Hoelder 
decomposition where the irreducible pieces could be weighted by a 
certain measure!). So it seems 
that it might be possible to define some kind of monoid structure 
on $\widehat{G}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is the answer that you looking for but anyway he we go. For a locally compact group you are going to generally want to look at strongly continuous representation. By this is mean endow $B(H)$, the bounded operators on a hilbert space $H$ with the topology of point-wise norm convergence. And only consider reps $\pi:G\rightarrow B(H)$ that are continuous with this topology. Now such a rep is unitary if, for every $g\in G$, $\pi(g)$ is a unitary operator.

Now the notion of "occur in" that you mention seems to be the notion of strong containment. We say that $\rho:G\rightarrow B(K)$ is strongly contained in $\pi:G\rightarrow B(H)$ if there is a $G$-equivarient unitary operator from $K$ to a closed subspace of $H$.

So it now seems that you are asking when does the left regular rep ($L^2(G)$) strongly contain all irreducibles. So yes for compact Lie groups this follows from Peter-weyl this is true.

However as soon as you go to something non-compact this might not be true.

In fact, there is a much weaker notion known as weak containment of representation. and it is known that $L^2(G)$ weakly contains all irreducible reps if and only if $G$ is amenable.

Non-compact Lie groups are in general not amenable, (any groups which contains $\mathbb{F}_2$ the free group on 2 generators is non-amenable)

There is much more to be said about this but I think that this should suffice for now

Comment: There's something I don't understand here.  One can embed the free group on two generators in the group $SO(3)$ of rotations in three dimensions, which is as compact as it gets.  So according to what you are saying, $SO(3)$ would not be amenable, whence $L^2(SO(3))$ would not contain all irreps (even weakly), contradicting Peter-Weyl.  Not being an expert, I'm surely confused... but where?

Comment: Right, sorry. The statement is the the embedding must be closed. The embedding into $SO(3)$ is not closed.

Answer (score 4):

For (1) and (3), there are plenty of irreducible unitary representations of SL2(R) that do not occur in the regular representation, such as complementary series, limits of discrete series, and for that matter the trivial representation.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks @Richard. Do you have a good reference where the author constructs all irreducible (no more unitary) representations of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$? I know that there is the book from Lang on $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ but there might be better references...

Comment: Hugo, you should take a look at Godement's Seminarie Bourbaki Expose "Introduction aux travaux de Selberg" (1957) where a proof of the Plancherel theorem for $SL_2(\mathbf R)$ is beautifully explained. For the construction of representations, I like Howe and Tan in "Nonabelian Harmonic Analysis".

Comment: Welcome, Amri !