# unitary irreps of O(p,q)

Tags: lie-groups, rt.representation-theory

I am interested in the irreducible unitary representations of the orthogonal groups $O(p,q)$.  By $O(p,q)$ I mean the real Lie groups which preserve the quadratic form of signature $(p,q)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n = p+q$ dimensions.  Special cases of interest in physics are the conformal group O(4,2), the deSitter group O(4,1) and the anti-deSitter group O(3,2) in dimension 4 = 3+1 (i.e. Minkowski space).  I am only interested in the non-compact groups, the compact cases being well-understood.  (So I expect that the irreducible unitary representations are all infinite dimensional.)  I am not exclusively interested in Lorentzian signature $n = (n-1) + 1$, nor am I exclusively interested in $n=4$. As a theoretical physicist, I am not familiar with the undoubtedly vast literature on representations of non-compact Lie groups, and I would appreciate a few pointers to the most relevant references; those that review the general setting, but especially which address these groups specifically.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: This link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37021/is-fourier-analysis-a-special-case-of-representation-theory-or-an-analogue/37189#37189 doesn't directly answer your question, but may provide some background.  My guess is that the unitary irreps. of $O(p,q)$ are not classified in general, but that a lot is known.  A key point is that as long as at least one of $p$ or $q$ is even, then the maximal compact $O(p) \times O(q)$ has the same rank as $O(p,q)$, and hence $O(p,q)$ admits discrete series representations.   Two possible references are: 

Comment: Knapp's "rep'n theory of semisimple Lie groups: an overview based on examples" (or something to that effect), which is long but gives a lot of detailed background, and Vogan's book "Unitary rep's of reductive Lie groups", which is more of a research monograph.  Neither will address $O(p,q)$ specifically, but will rather treat aspects of the general theory, so they won't be exactly what you want by any means.  One other thing, just in case you don't know: "unitary dual" is the technical term for the set of unitary irreps. of a semisimple or reductive Lie group, and so googling for this

Comment: term is one way to try to get information.  

Comment: Also, you could try this site: http://www.liegroups.org/

Comment: Some questions about Irreps of O(p,q) considered by Sergei Gukov  http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2218 , as an application of "brane quantization" approach to solve some concerete problems. But probably you this... 

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. To try to sharpen my question a bit, let me give a bit more context.  In 1939 Wigner classified all of the irreducible unitary representations of the Poincare group (semi-direct product of the Lorentz group and the group of translations in 3+1 dimensional Minkowski space).  Minkowski space is flat, but deSitter and anti-deSitter space have constant curvature, and are also maximally symmetric, with isometry groups O(4,1) and O(3,2).  I would be quite happy to understand the classification of their (infinite-dimensional) irreducible unitary representations. 

Comment: Although the question is motivated by physics considerations, I believe the question is mathematically well-posed: is there a classification of the irreducible unitary representations of the Lie groups O(4,1) and O(3,2), and more generally for O(p,q) for all p and q.  Hope this clarifies the question a bit.

Comment: Dear Mark, I don't think there is a written out classification for $O(p,q)$ for general $p,q$ --- if you look at some of the links I sent, then for general semisimple groups the unitary dual is not written down, although for any particular group computing it is a finite (athough not necessarily tractable) problem.  On the other hand, for $O(4,1)$ and $O(3,2)$ it is presumably a tractable problem.
Regards, Matthew

Comment: Dear Mark, This paper: http://www.liegroups.org/papers/computing.pdf explains the general procedure for computing the unitary dual.  It's presumably simpler in your lowish rank cases than in general.  The key points are to (a) identify the way that the tempered reps. decompose; (b) find the complementary series.  It is the complementary series that become harder to classify as the rank goes up.  Regards,

Comment: Emerton - thank you for pointing me to the Vogan paper.  This has opened up a useful search direction. --Mark

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The unitary dual of Spin(n,1) is known for all n (Hirai, 1962, see Math Reviews MR0696689).
This gives the unitary dual of the identity component of SO(n,1) (which is a quotient 
of Spin(n,1)). The unitary dual of any group can be deduced readily from that of its identity 
component. Also SL(2,C)=Spin(3,1), and SL(2,R)=Spin(2,1).

The unitary dual of Sp(4,R) is known (Nzoukoudi, 1983, MR0736241), and Sp(4,R)=Spin(3,2).
The unitary dual of SU(2,2) is known (Knapp/Speh, 1982, MR0645645), and SU(2,2)=Spin(4,2). These 
give the unitary duals of SO(3,2) and SO(4,2).

Besides this (and the compact groups) I think the entire unitary dual is not known
for any O(p,q), although for any fixed group a large part of its unitary dual is known. You might look at some papers by Welleda Baldoni and Tony Knapp from the 1980s or so.

Note: much of the literature applies to groups of "Harish-Chandra's class".
This includes all SO(p,q), but O(p,q) only if p+q is odd. So if p+q is even you
have to do a little extra work to get from the unitary dual of SO(p,q) to that
of O(p,q) (for each irreducible unitary representation of SO(p,q) you have to decide
if its induction to O(p,q) has 1 or 2 irreducible summands).

As for www.liegroups.org, we hope to have the complete answer for any group, but
that day has not yet arrived.