# Unitary dual of $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Do we know the unitary dual of $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$? If so, can someone provide me any references? How about other rank 2 real groups? Thank you!

Comment: You find GL(3) and GL(4) as well as SL(3) and SL(4) in a paper by Speh: The unitary dual of Gl(3,R) and Gl(4,R). 
Math. Ann. 258 (1981/82), no. 2, 113–133.

Comment: The paper by Speh is here: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002321386 You should also consult Vogan's lectures and papers, in particular http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002111934

Comment: Thank you! I found Vogan's paper on the unitary dual of GL(n), and also Knapp's paper on SU(2,2), but how about other rank 2 groups?

Comment: Did you try google?  Vogan, "The unitary dual of G2", Invent. math. (1994).

Comment: @Geordie : I tried. And I am more into the classical groups, not exceptional groups. But thank you for your notice.

Comment: See the answer to: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84624