# Unitary representations of SO(1,4) and SO(2,3)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations, noncompact

Where can I find details about the irreducible unitary representations of SO(1,4) and SO(2,3)?

Comment: This is a special case of MO question on [unitary irreps of O(p,q)](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84624/unitary-irreps-of-op-q/84762#84762)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Volume 2, Chapter 9 of the monumental (4-volume!) work of N. Ya. Vilenkin and A. U. Klimyk, *Representations of Lie Groups and Special Functions* (Kluwer, 1993).

Answer (score 2):

The unitary dual of SO(1,4) was computed by [Dixmier (1961)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=140614); that of SO(2,3), or the locally isomorphic Sp(2,**R**), by [Angelopoulos (1981)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=612538) and [Nzoukoudi (1983)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=736241).

Comment: Hmm, all these are in French. Is there also a description in English?