# Plancherel expansion for Spin(n-1,1)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am interested in the principal series (unitary irreducible) representations of $Spin(n-1,1)$, and in the generalized Pancherel's formula for the delta function on the group in terms of a sum (and an integral) of characters:

$$ \delta(g) = \int \dots \sum_{\dots} \text{tr} W_{\dots} (g), $$

where $\dots$ represent the continuous and discrete parameters labeling the irrep from the principal series.

I already know that principal irreps have been classified for $Spin(2,1) \sim SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $Spin(3,1)\sim SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. I am interested in the general case of $Spin(n-1, 1)$, or at least in $Spin(5,1)$ and $Spin(7,1)$.

Comment: did you try google search?

Comment: @Venkataramana I don't see the point of your comment. Yes, I searched for this, and I haven't find anything useful. Did you find something useful? If I missed it, please share your findings with me.

Comment: See [Unitary Representations of O(p,q)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84624/unitary-irreps-of-op-q/84762#84762)

Answer (score 1):

Knapp ([1986, p. 736](https://books.google.com/books?id=QCcW1h835pwC&pg=PA736&ots=C9wgcgMOde)) attributes the Plancherel formula for real-rank-one groups to Okamoto ([1965](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=219668)), Hirai ([1966](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=206155)), and Harish-Chandra ([1966](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=194556)). More details in Sally-Warner ([1973](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=450461)), Miatello ([1979](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=545044)).