# A Fourier elliptic vector field on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, fourier-transform

**Motivation for this question:**

Let $X$ be a vector field on a manifold $M$. Obviously the differential operator $D:C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ with $D(f)=X.f$ is not an elliptic opetator when $\dim M>1$. Now consider a simple example: Put $M$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, $X=x^2\partial_x+y^2 \partial_y$
and $D$ for the first order corresponding differential operator. Then if we dente by $\mathcal{F}$ the standard Fourier transform operator then the principal (last homogeneus) part of differential operator  $\mathcal{F}^{-1} D \mathcal{F}$ is $xu_{xx} +yu_{yy}$. This operator is an elliptic operator if we restrict to the first positive quadrant $x>0, y>0$.This situation is discussed via some other quadratic system in Remark 2 and its consecutive example in page 5 of this [note](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0001).

In this question we would like to globalize and generalize this situation.

**Fourier transform on Riemannian manifolds and Lie groups**

In [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/does-a-fourier-transformation-on-a-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-make-sense) three methods of generalization of Fourier transform on a Riemannian manifold or a Lie group is discussed. So based on these definition we assume that the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ is a linear isomorphism on $C^{\infty}(M)$ when $M$ is a Riemannian manifold.

**Definition:** A non-vanishing vector field $X$ with derivational operator $D$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ or a Lie group $G$ is called **Fourier elliptic vector field** if the differential operator $\mathcal{F}^{-1}D\mathcal{F}$ gives us a global elliptic operator.

> **Question:** What are some precise examples of both Riemannian manifold and Lie group cases which admit a Fourier  elliptic vector field?  Does every manifold $ M$ with a non-vanishing vector field $X$ admit a Riemannian metric such that the vector field $X$ would be a Fourier elliptic vector field?

Comment: I wrote the linked MSE post. NONE of the three notions I described give you that the "Fourier transform is a linear isomorphism on $C^\infty(M)$". The closest case is that of the second notion, and even there the Fourier transform takes function spaces on a Lie group $G$ to functions defined on its dual group $\hat{G}$. For example, if you consider the group $\mathbb{T}^k$, its dual group is $\mathbb{Z}^k$. I am not sure how you intend to even define a differential operator on the dual group.

Comment: Shouldn't the considered Fourier transform be defined on an analogue of the Schwartz class on $M$ to get an automorphism  thereof?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN When $M$ is compact, there is no distinction between $C^\infty$ and $\mathcal{S}$; on the other hand, when $M$ is compact, most notions of frequencies will require the frequency space to be discrete and not a $\mathrm{dim}(M)$ dimensional manifold. For the case of Lie groups, it is also more convenient to formulate the general theory in terms of $L^2$ rather than $\mathcal{S}$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37021/is-fourier-analysis-a-special-case-of-representation-theory-or-an-analogue

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN  yes it was a typo. As you said it is  Schartz space. I wrote in paragraph 3 of the  arxived note I mentioned in the post.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thank you for  your  MO  links. With help of these two  MO and  MSE  link(your  answer) I hope that one can introduce  an abstract  and global version I am searching for. To be  honnest I am interested to find  a  generalization and  globalization of  this  situation since more than 7 years ago. In fact after I posted that note to arxive, I realized that the resulting $\mathcal{F}^{-1}D\mathcal{F}$ is  not  GLOBALLY  elliptic. So I wonder if there exist a  vector field on the plane for  which $D$ preserves the Schwartz class  and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}D\mathcal{F}$ is globally elliptic

Comment: For  example  does  $D=cos x \partial_x +sin x \partial_y$ work?

Comment: What exactly is the notion of elliptic you are working with? Your operator $F^{-1}D F$ for general vector fields $D$ (on $\mathbb{R}^2$) is not going to be a differential operator. I am not even sure it can in general be a pseudodifferential operator.

Comment: @WillieWong A differential operator is a linear operator which decreases the support(according to Peetre theirem). So an elliptic one has an obvious definition. For polynomial vector field  the resulting $F^{-1} D F$ is obviousely a differential operator. But as you said it is interesting to classify all $D$ whose $F^{-1}DF$ is restriction of a differential operatir from $C^{\infty}$ to Schwartz space.

Comment: @WillieWong  Now I realize what you say. but when the coefficients are polynomial functions the resulting $F^{-1}DF$ is a diff. operator again. Please read example in page 5 of this note(befor Remark 3)  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0001.pdf

Comment: In this case: your $F^{-1} D F$ can be expressed as $P\ell$, where $\ell$ is a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $P$ is a constant coefficient partial differential operator. Its classification is not too technical.

Comment: @What is this linear functional for $D$ say $D=x^2\partial_x+y^2\partial_y+xy \Delta$?

Comment: Delta is Laplacian

Comment: The main aim of this question is to remedy the non ellipticity of certain linear operator associated to a derivational operator.

Comment: In fact the non ellipticity which discussed in this post was the main motivation for our question:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields?rq=1